# Laravel policy in blade doesn't understand how work

Tags: laravel-5

I'm noob in Laravel, I have written a policy and I have used it in blade template, and I don't understand how work the parameter match. 
Shnippets from my code:

**UserPolicy.php**

```
public function hasModifyUserStatus(User $currentUser, $editableUser) {
    echo $currentUser->id.' | '.$editableUser->id;
    ...
```

**userform.blade**

```
@can('hasModifyUserStatus', $editableUser, $editableUser->id)
```

the results: 1 | 3 where 1 is my current user 3 is the editable user id.

so, in the `$currentuser` is the `Auth::user()` and in the `editableUser` is the really `editableuser`, but in `@can` I put the `$editableUser` and the `$editableUser->id` :)
So I don't understand how it is working.

Could somebody help me? 
(I have read the documentations, but I haven't found and I'm looking it more than 2 hours :-) )

My Laravel version is 5.2 with PHP 7.

Comment: OK, what is the real UserPolicy code, Policies should Boolean values, without echoing anything.

Comment: This is tho whole method now, it's working, just I don't understand how :-)
`public function hasModifyUserStatus(User $currentUser, $editableUser) {
        //echo $currentUser->id." | ".$editableUser->id;
        if($currentUser->id == $editableUser->id) {
            return false;
        }

        return $currentUser->isSystemAdmin();
    }`

Comment: Do you have the new Policy registered in the AuthServiceProvider?